# a function which read integers using scanf but crash if enter letters

Tags: c

I am new to `C` and I want to write a function that reads a sequence of whitespace-separated integers from standard input until the maximum count is reached or `EOF` occurs or a non-integer is encountered. `maxNumInts` is the maximum number of integers to be read, `nums` is an array of at least `maxNumInts` integers, into which the integers are read. The return value of `readInts()` is the number of integers read into the array `nums`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[]) {
    int count = 0;

    while (scanf("%d", &nums[count++]) != EOF && count < maxNumInts) {
    }   
    return count;   
}

int main() {
    int nums[5] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    int n = readInts(4, nums);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);
    }
}
```

I tested by entering numbers and it worked but when 
I tried to test it by entering:

```
10 100 1000 Oops -999
It returns:n = 4
nums[0] = 10
nums[1] = 100
nums[2] = 1000
nums[3] = -1
nums[4] = -1
```

`n` is supposed to be `3`. How could I fix it? I prefer to use `scanf()`.

Comment: `while(scanf("%d",&nums[count++]) != EOF && ...)` Please lookup the man page for `scanf` to check the return value. It never returns `EOF`.

Comment: @Gerhardh [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns `EOF`. The OP should take the the return value of `scanf()` in a variable and check whether it is `0` (in case of matching failure) or `EOF`.

Comment: @H.S. You are right, my fault. I forgot about the part in the manual where it could be EOF instead of 0. But here it should be a matching error, not an input error if I get it right.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, `scanf()` must be returning `0` when it encounters input `Oops`.

Comment: strongly suggest the `while()` loop be written as: `  while( count < maxNumInts &&  scanf( "%d", &nums[count++] ) == 1 )
 {
  count++;
 }`  to enable the proper order of evaluation and to properly check the returned value from `scanf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with code

**Key issue: Wrong success checking**

`scanf("%d",&nums[count++])` returns 1 on success, 0 with invalid input and `EOF` for end of file or input error.

`scanf("%d",&nums[count++]) != EOF` is true with valid and invalid input.

`scanf("%d",&nums[count++]) == 1` is true with valid numeric input.

**Wrong `count`**

Code increments `count` even when `scanf()` failed to read a valid `int`.

```
// while(scanf("%d",&nums[count++]) == 1 ...) {
while(scanf("%d",&nums[count]) == 1 ...) {
  count++;  // Increment here
}
```

**Checking size too late**

OP's code can access `nums[count]` when `count` is already too high.  Better to check `count < maxNumInts` before attempting to read data.  [@user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768447/a-function-which-read-integers-using-scanf-but-crash-if-enter-letters/51773225#comment90497403_51768447) This has a side benefit of leaving un-read data in `stdin` for other code to process versus reading it here and then not saving it.

```
// re-order to
while(count < maxNumInts && scanf("%d",&nums[count]) == 1) {
  count++;
}
```

**No overflow protection**

When the integer as text does not convert to a value in the `int` range, 
code increments `count` even when `scanf()` failed to read a valid `int`, `scanf("%d"...` is *undefined behavior* when overflow occurs.

**Confusing magic number 4**

`readInts(4, nums)` uses 4 for the `maxNumInts` when 5 would make more sense.  Best to derive the number from `nums` than code a naked value like 4 or 5.

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[])
  ... 

int nums[5] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
// int n = readInts(4, nums);
ElementCount = sizeof nums/sizeof nums[0];
int n = readInts(4, ElementCount);
```

---

Example fix

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[]) {
  int count = 0;
  while(count < maxNumInts && scanf("%d", &nums[count]) == 1) {
    count++;
    }   
  return count;   
}
```

Note: overflow protect not yet implemented.

Answer (score 3):

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[])
{
    int count = 0;

    while(scanf("%d",&nums[count++]) != EOF && count < maxNumInts) {
        }   
    return count;   
}
```

you are incrementing `count` even on the call which fails. Also scanf returns the number of items read and thus will return zero not EOF when it doesn't read anything.

Try

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[])
{
    int count = 0;

    while((1 == scanf("%d",&nums[count])) && (count < maxNumInts)) {
           count++;
    }   
    return count;   
}
```

I strongly recommend that you get an IDE, such as [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) or some other which you like.

Then learn about the debugger

- how to set breakpoints
- how to examine variables
- how to step though your code line by line
- how to examine the call stack
- etc

[image]

Since you seem to be new, be aware of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ When your code is working, post it there and you will get advice on how to improve it (such a `n` is not a very meaningful variable name)

When you can do that, you will never again have to wait for out help for issues like this, because you can find them easily in the debugger.

Comment: What makes you think that `count` is never incremented?

Comment: No problems; I have days like that too :-)

Comment: In the while condition shouldn't count be range checked before using it in scanf?

Comment: Consider `readInts(2, nums)` to read into a `int nums[2]`.  This answer recommends to read into `scanf("%d",&nums[2])` before quitting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the count variable in the loop that fails. You should put the increment after the while conditions like:

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[]) 
{

    int count = 0;

    while (scanf("%d",&nums[count]) != EOF && count < maxNumInts) {
           count++;
    }   
    return count;   
 }
```

Comment: Note that this goes into an infinite loop when it tries to read an integer out of `oops` as in the question.  You should probably check for `== 1` instead of `!= EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `scanf()` and increase the `count` only if the `scanf()` has successfully assigned the receiving argument.

Also, the array `nums` is of size `5` and you are passing the size `1` less than the size of array `nums` to `readInts()` function:

```
int n = readInts(4, nums);
                 ^
```

This will confuse the reader. Instead, you should pass the actual size of array which is `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])`.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readInts(size_t maxNumInts, int nums[])
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while((scanf("%d", &nums[count]) == 1) && (++count < maxNumInts)) {
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[5] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
    int n = readInts(sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]), nums);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input loop has 3 bugs:

- you call `scanf()` even if `maxNumInts` is `0` (not causing problems in your case, but incorrect).
- `count` is incremented even if the conversion fails.
- the result of `scanf()` is not correctly tested, so the loop continues repeatedly when `Oops` fails to convert to an `int`.

`scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions or `EOF` at end of file. Testing for `EOF` alone is incorrect as `scanf()` will return `0` on invalid input, such as letters.

In the input loop, the steps should be performed in this order:

1. test if the maximum count is reached
2. call `scanf()` to attempt the next conversion
3. increment the count and continue if the conversion is successful, otherwise stop.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[]) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < maxNumInts && scanf("%d", &nums[count]) == 1; count++)
        continue;
    return count;   
}
```